# how do i get imagedownloadservice to work with multilist component in codenameone?

Tags: codenameone

I have created a multi list in GUI Designer. I am setting the model as below

```
   @Override
protected boolean initListModelMultiIssueList(List cmp) {
    fetchIssues(cmp);
    if (issueVector != null ) {
    cmp.setModel(new DefaultListModel(issueVector));
    System.out.println(cmp);
    }
    return true;
}
void fetchIssues( List c){
    //fetch issues based on the searchquery hash
    //first thing is to create the query from the hash
    System.out.println("Starting to fetch results");
    try{
        java.util.List<ServiceRequest> serviceRequests = ServiceRequest.getServiceRequests(formQuery(searchQuery),true);
        //we need to now populate the issueVector
        //with the data
        System.out.println(serviceRequests.toString());
        if (issueVector != null ) {
            issueVector.clear();
        } else {
            issueVector = new Vector();
        } 
        int index = 0;
        for (ServiceRequest serviceRequest : serviceRequests) {
                Hashtable hIssue = new Hashtable();
                hIssue.put("id",serviceRequest.getHref());
                //System.out.println(hIssue); 

                ImageDownloadService.createImageToStorage(serviceRequest.getRequestPictureURL().toString(),
                        c, index, "icon", 
                        "service-icon-"+ index ,null);
                //hIssue.put("icon", serviceRequest.getRequestPictureURL().toString());
                //System.out.println(hIssue);
                //reverse geocode the location
                Double x = new Double(0.0);
                x=new Double(serviceRequest.getRequestLocationLatitude());
                Double y = new Double(serviceRequest.getRequestLocationLongitude());
                String location=reverseGeocode(x, y);
                hIssue.put("location", location);
                //System.out.println(hIssue);
                Service service = serviceRequest.loadService();
                hIssue.put("service", serviceRequest.loadService().getName().toString());
                hIssue.put("reportedOn",serviceRequest.getCreatedAt().toString());
                //System.out.println("Final hIssue" + hIssue.toString());
                issueVector.add(hIssue);
                index=index+1;
                System.out.println(issueVector);
        }

    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error loading search results");
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

The icon in the multi list GUI design has been set to the appropriate property. ImageDownloadService does download the image files but then it does not display in the list as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Its possible that the image is downloaded before the entry is available. Although its hard to tell with the code and without a clear explanation of the symptoms.

You need to first create the model and set it to the list (ideally with a blank placeholder image so the list doesn't "jump"). Then you need to loop over the list and invoke the image download service, otherwise it might return before the data is in the list and fail! This can happen if the image is already in cache so its very likely to fail fast in that case.

Comment: OK. If I understand you correctly, I should create the model and set to the list. So in my code, I should call fetchIssues() after setting the model and not before. I'll try.

Comment: Tried but does not work. The understanding is that first of all build list and set to model and display. Then loop through list again and use imagedownloadservice to update. It is required that the icon be already defined in the list with some placeholder value which imagedownloadservice will replace. I'll try and be clear and see if i can achieve.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Did you run it in the debugger? Do you get an exception? Did you look in the demos such as the facebook demo where this is used?

Comment: I can see the image is downloaded but it does not show on the list. I will look again at the Facebook demo.